# Modify struct in union to other value in union without copy

Tags: c, memory, struct, unions

I have this struct :

```
typedef struct sPixelRGB {
    int r;
    int g;
    int b;
} sPixel;

typedef struct tsImagePPM {
    long imax;
    sPixel ** array;
} sImagePPM;

typedef struct tsImagePGM {
    long imax;
    int ** grey;   
} sImagePGM;

union imgType{
   sImagePPM imgP;
   sImagePGM imgG;
 };

typedef struct sImage{
   union imgType sImg;
   long height;
   long width;
   int type;
}img;
```

It represent a PPM (rgb) or PGM (only grey) Image (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format).

I have to transform my picture, originally a PPM, to a PGM, by the simple following formula :

```
grey = 0.299 × r + 0.587 × g + 0.114 × b
```

I want to use this struct with an union because of the others functions I had to do. And I'm wondering if it is possible to modify the sImg.imgP to sImg.imG without making a new sImagePPM, filling it with the new grey value, and then affecting it to the union.

More generally, I'm wondering if it is possible to do something like this :

```
//img imgPM is initialize
imgPM.sImg.imgG.imax = imgPM.sImg.imgP.imax 
for (i = 0 ; i < width ;  i++){
    for (j = 0 ; j < height ;  j++){
        imgPM.sImg.imgG[i][j] = imgPM.sImg.imgP[i][j]
```

Because, when I was reading my Image from a file, I didn't see that I forgot to change the imgP to an imgG when I read PGM image, and displaying the imax of the PGM struct was possible, even if I had initialize a PGM struct in the union.

I'm not sure how it works regarding the memory, even though I read a lot of things about it.

Comment: Is the `v` a typo and should by `g`?

Comment: Yeah, it's a typo (I copied the formula which is in French)

Comment: Member of a union share memory, they occupy the exact same memory. Considering that both `sImagePPM` and `sImagePGM` are the exact same size and layout, the, both the pointers will be equal. What you seem to want to be doing would overwrite the data you read from.

Comment: Yeah, it's what I would like to do, but since it's not from the same struct, isn't there a problem by editing the data one by one, and having a half `sImagePPM`, and half `sImagePGM` value inside the union ?

Comment: While the types of the structures in the union may be different, the memory isn't. If you make `imgPM.sImg.imgG.grey` point somewhere, then automatically `imgPM.sImg.imgP.array` will as well, to the very same location. You can't switch between members of a union like that (unless you do *type punning*, which you aren't).

Comment: Just FYI, image formats pixels are typically laid out from top left to top right, then down to the next row, so you should probably switch your loops around, so that width is in the innermost loop.  (Actually you _can_ treat it as a 1d array of width*height)

Comment: I'm used to read it like this because of my mental representation of 2d array. I treated it at 1d array in the past, but here it's not interesting because of some operation we have to do). But thanks for the information.

Comment: If you don't at least switch the loops though, you will get a cache miss on every single pixel.

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't see I failed this, my bad you're right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `imax` member of the struct should be accessible. If the union contains a `sImagePPM`, when you try to access the `imG` member, the representation of the `sImagePPM` is reinterpreted as a representation for a `sImagePGM` struct. The first member of the struct has the address of the struct, so the first bytes of the representation of the `imP` member will be the representation of what was `imP.imax`.

As two numbers with same representation shall have same value `imgPM.sImg.imgG.imax` shall have the value that `imgPM.sImg.imgP.imax had`.

Things will probably be worse for the pointers because a `sPixel` and an `int` are different types and so are pointers and pointers to pointers to them.

Only in the case where all the arrays of `sPixels` and the array of pointers to them are dynamically allocated, you can reuse the memory because as dynamic memory has no declared type, it receives the type of the data which is written there. But in that case, it would be simpler to allocate a new block of memory for a `int **` and `int *` arrays, compute value of all pixels from the `sPixel array`, then affect  the newly computed array to the `imgPM.sImg.imgG.grey` member and free memory used by the `sPixel` arrays.

Comment: I wanted to do something like this, with a new array, but our teacher (I'm doing this for school) doesn't want us to copy an array. If we have to copy an array we have to do it value by value, or affecting it by reference in an init function for exemple.
It was why I search for this, since I'm wasn't sure how union work on the memory side